# Creating databases in SQLAlchemy tests with PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pyramid, pytest

I am building a Pyramid web application which is built on the top of SQLAlchemy and solely relies PostgreSQL as its database backend.

What would be a way to have the unit tests structure so that

- Database is built once per test run - not on every test `setUp()` as this is too slow for a complex application
- Database tables are (re)created as they would be created in production (e.g. run migrations from Alembic). Any unclean databases are destroyed at the start of the test run.
- It is possible to choose a custom test runner á la `py.test` if a specific features outside the standard library unittest framework makes it easier to write test cases.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29507883/rolling-back-database-transactions-in-sqlalchemy-tests-with-postgresql

Comment: Related: https://gist.github.com/inklesspen/4504383

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Nose](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) test runner supports `setup_package()` and `teardown_package()` methods. Here's an excerpt from the docs:

> [**Test Packages**](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing_tests.html#test-packages)
>
> nose allows tests to be grouped into test packages. This allows
>   package-level setup; for instance, if you need to create a test
>   database or other data fixture for your tests, you may create it in
>   package setup and remove it in package teardown once per test run,
>   rather than having to create and tear it down once per test module or
>   test case.
>
> To create package-level setup and teardown methods, define setup
>   and/or teardown functions in the **init**.py of a test package. Setup
>   methods may be named setup, setup_package, setUp, or setUpPackage;
>   teardown may be named teardown, teardown_package, tearDown or
>   tearDownPackage. Execution of tests in a test package begins as soon
>   as the first test module is loaded from the test package.

In my application I have `setup_package()` which looks roughly like the following:

```
def _create_database():

    template_engine = sa.create_engine("postgres://postgres@/postgres", echo=False)

    conn = template_engine.connect()
    conn = conn.execution_options(autocommit=False)
    conn.execute("ROLLBACK")
    try:
        conn.execute("DROP DATABASE %s" % DB_NAME)
    except sa.exc.ProgrammingError as e:
        # Could not drop the database, probably does not exist
        conn.execute("ROLLBACK")
    except sa.exc.OperationalError as e:
        # Could not drop database because it's being accessed by other users (psql prompt open?)
        conn.execute("ROLLBACK")

    conn.execute("CREATE DATABASE %s" % DB_NAME)
    conn.close()

    template_engine.dispose()


def setup_package():
    _create_database()

    engine = sa.create_engine("postgres://postgres@/%s" % DB_NAME, echo=False)

    session = sa.orm.scoped_session(sa.orm.sessionmaker())
    session.configure(bind=engine)
    Base.metadata.bind = engine
    Base.metadata.create_all()


def teardown_package():
    # no need to do anything as the old database is dropped at the start of every run
```

In addition, all test case classes are subclassed from a base class, which, importantly, defines a common `tearDown` method:

```
class BaseTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        # This makes things nicer if the previous test fails
        # - without this all subsequent tests fail
        self.tearDown()

        self.config = testing.setUp()

    def tearDown(self):
        testing.tearDown()
        session.expunge_all()
        session.rollback()
```

Subclasses often override base `setUp`, but there usually no need to override `tearDown` - by rolling back the transaction it ensures that the next test will start on a completely clean database.

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but how does the BaseTest tearDown know what `session` is?