# Rolling back database transactions in SQLAlchemy tests with PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I am building a Pyramid web application which is built on the top of SQLAlchemy and solely relies PostgreSQL as its database backend.

What would be a way to have the unit tests structure so that

- To speed up tests, database transactions are rolled back at the `teardown()`, or other clean up hook of the test suite
- Other tricks to speed up tests could be used, e.g. if SQLAlchemy and PostgreSQL has anything corresponding SQLite's `:in:memory:` database
- It is possible to choose a custom test runner á la `py.test` if a specific features outside the standard library unittest framework makes it easier to write test cases.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29507792/creating-databases-in-sqlalchemy-tests-with-postgresql

Comment: Related: https://gist.github.com/inklesspen/4504383

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7872693/398670

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9407442/398670

Comment: A good trick is to create a "template" database with all the tables and data you need for your test, and do a create database newdb template testtemplate; and use the testtemplate db and when you're done with it just drop it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this question is a bit similar to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29507792/creating-databases-in-sqlalchemy-tests-with-postgresql), I'll copy the relevant part of my answer here:

All test case classes should be subclassed from a base class, which defines a common tearDown method:

```
class BaseTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        # This makes things nicer if the previous test fails
        # - without this all subsequent tests fail
        self.tearDown()

        self.config = testing.setUp()

    def tearDown(self):
        testing.tearDown()
        session.expunge_all()
        session.rollback()
```

Answer (score 1):

For tests you can initialize PostgreSQL data directory on a RAMdisk (you can create a directory under `/dev/shm/`, which is mounted as `tmpfs` in modern Linux distributions). The you can run Postgres on non-standard port.

```
PGTEMP=`mktemp -d /dev/shm/pgtemp.XXXXXX`
initdb -D "$PGTEMP"
postgres -D "$PGTEMP" -k "$PGTEMP" -p 54321
```